# How to get count of foreign key relationship for each instance in queryset?

Tags: python, django

I have the following Models:

```
# app_a/models.py

class Poller(models.Model):
    poller_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# app_b/models.py

class PollerComment(models.Model):
    poller = models.ForeignKey(Poller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='PollerComment')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And this view to render the template:

```
def render_pollboard(request):

    # Query Pollers
    poller_queryset = Poller.objects.all()

    # Convert to list
    qs_list = list(poller_queryset)

    # Shuffle the list
    shuffle(qs_list)

    # Retrieve comment count per Poller
    comments_qs = PollerComment.objects.filter(poller_id=poller.poller_id)
[..]
```

In the view I try to get the comment count for each Poller in `poller_queryset`. How to do this?

Side note: I tried to implement the comment count as a method to the Poller model, but due to my design this leads into a circular import error of module of app_b/models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) here:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Poller.objects.annotate(
    ncomments=Count('PollerComment')
)
```

`Poller` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.ncomments` with the number of *related* `PollerComment`s.

If you thus use this as the `poller_queryset`, you can use this in your template as:

```
{% for poller in qs_list %}
    {{ poller.poller_id }}: {{ poller.ncomments }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks again @willem. The view returns `Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.` now. I do have objects with 0 comments, might this be an issue?

Comment: @Jonas: sorry I made a typo, it is `Count('PollerComment')` so wrapped in a string literal.

Comment: Ah cool, works now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the poller instance to get the count of its foreign keys

```
for poll in poller_queryset:
    poll.PollerComment_set.count() // gives you the count of comment for that poll
```

also you can use `Count`

```
from django.db.models import Count
Poller.objects.annotate(
    ncomments=Count(PollerComment)
)
```